# How to add an optional "param" in a regular expression in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I've following 2 rules in my .htaccess file -

```
1. RewriteRule ^myscript/([A-Za-z0-9]{0,1})\?page=([0-9]?)$ /myscript.php?action=check&var=$1&page=$2 [L]
2. RewriteRule ^myscript/([A-Za-z0-9]{0,1})$ /myscript.php?action=check&var=$1 [L]
```

so that visitng `/myscript/d` sends a request as `/myscript.php?action=check&var=d`
I am trying to add an option page parameter so that visiting /myscript/d?page=5 sends the requests as `/myscript.php?action=check&var=d&page=5`

to achieve this I tried this

```
RewriteRule ^myscript/([A-Za-z0-9]{0,1})\?page=([0-9]?)$ /myscript.php?action=check&var=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

But this rules is being ignored and the request is sent as /myscript.php?action=check&var=d (i.e. 2nd rule from the above is being applied). What am I doing wrong here? What changes do I need to make it get it working?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not make the URL `/myscript/d/5/`? So, if it contains the extra value pass it to the page parameter? Besides, there is no need to do a rewrite for the extra parameter the way you have it now. You just access it with `$_GET['page']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2nd rule only and add `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^myscript/([A-Za-z0-9]{0,1})$ /myscript.php?action=check&var=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will pass existing query parameter to the new URL:

```
/myscript/d?page=5&say=hello
=>
/myscript.php?action=check&var=d&page=5&say=hello
```

**Apache documentation:** http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Fantastic!! I learnt that I could not escape ? (question mark) in the regex which was causing this rule not to work. QSA works just great. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Kay `RewriteRule` does not work with query string directly -- only with help of `RewriteCond`; therefore your rule #1 will never get executed regardless how you will escape `?` -- everything after `?` (including the symbol itself) is not part of the matching string -- RewriteRule works with path part of the URI only.